# Html height buffer zones

Tags: html, css

So the story is this:

I'm making a website in which the homepage content is consisted of a menu and the clients logo. 
But the way I've design it, the content needs to be in the center of the browser window... So across the board, because everyone has different screen heights, everyone who views the website either has too much white space under the footer, or part of the content is cut off.

This is the website: http://thinkinternational.co/

So my idea to fix it was this: 
I created a buffer zone above the body, as you can see in the code below, but the problem I've discovered with having a percentage as a div height is that the parent div needs to have a specific height in the first place. Unfortunately, I'm not omniscient, and I can't predict every size of screen for every person who views this website, so I can't give it a specific height, otherwise I might as well have just left it as is in the first place.

Also, at the same time, I need the background to shift down with the body. Just to shake things up.

Any solutions for this issue ??

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="TopBuffer"></div>
  <div id="body" class="clearfix">
      Content Here
  </div>   
</div>


body {
    background:#0b0b0b url(images/Slices/BackgroundHome.jpg) no-repeat center -150px fixed;
    -moz-background-size: inherit;
    -o-background-size: inherit;
    -webkit-background-size: inherit;
    background-size: inherit;
    height: 100%; }

main { color:#000; font-family:Arial,Geneva,sans-serif; margin:15px 0;height: 100%; }

TopBuffer { width:100%; height:25%; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, to make a height with percentage work, you will need the parent to have a specific height.
So `height:100%` on `body` will work once you put it on `html` too.
(I would also remove the margin and padding from `html`)

```
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And to make your background stretch all the way down, you will need make changes in this line of the CSS:

```
body{
    background:#0b0b0b url(images/Slices/BackgroundHome.jpg) no-repeat center -150px fixed;
}
```

change the `center -150px` to `center center`, to `center top` or to `center bottom` depending on which you prefer so you can show the whole image on larger resolutions.

First `center` is the horizontal position of background, and second one is vertical position.

As for centering your content vertically this is a nice article:

[Vertical Centering With CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/)

Comment: That's great, thank you... I need to play with it some more, and test it in a few more screens to make sure it works, and adjust the percentage.

Comment: for the background tho, is it possible to have it basically match the content exactly? The client wants the menu on the TOP rows of cubes.... Is that still possible in some way?

Comment: @NonaDobbs If you need your content centered vertically, and the background visible on all the screen, then I'm afraid not, you will have to give up one of the option.

Comment: Mmm. Think maybe the best way to attack this one is to fix everything together, then have the according buffers? The background I can make to look whatever way necessary, just by playing with the image... I'll give something else a try, and see how far I get.The vertical center is the most important part. If I can get that right, I can make adjustments to everything else

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript then use window.outerHeight to get the browser height and set the buffer according to that using javascript or jquery